# Windows 7 notebook turn off by itself, how to check if it is due to CPU being too hot?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, motherboard, fan, temperature

I have a Dell Studio 15 notebook, and it just started turning off by itself yesterday.

Could it be that the CPU is too hot?  I have had several notebooks before and every one of them I can put them on the bed without any problem.  This Dell Studio Notebook, however, seems like have the air / fan outlet pointed outward from the bottom back of the notebook,  so I suspect that the air is partially blocked when it is on the bed.

Are there Win 7 tools that can monitor the CPU temperature, or will some 3rd party tool be needed?  (I try to stick to official tools nowadays).

Also, it is running Win 7 Ulitmate, there is actually no utility or background service from Win 7 or from Dell that detects when the temperature is too hot (or 95% near the max), pop out a message box giving a warning and say that the computer will go into sleep mode in 1 minute, but instead just turn off the computer by brute force (cutting out the power) right then and there?

**Update**: it turned off right in front of my eyes -- it is not doing any windows update or anything.  just normal use and jooooop, it turned off.

**Update 2**: the battery is also bad, so when I unplug the power adapter cord, the notebook will turn off right away.  So I suspected can the battery be the thing that is causing the "auto turn off".  Sure enough, when I unplug the battery from the notebook, the notebook now NEVER turns off by itself.  I have had a bad battery from Macbook and Apple replaced the battery for me for free (the battery "auto expanded in size").  I wonder if Dell will do the same even if the notebook is outside the warranty period, if the battery is defective to begin with or had a recall -- they might do it on a "case by case" basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php), it was made for this stuff :)

The turning off is **not** done in software, it's an emergency, hopefully-should-never-happen, last-ditch total cut-off of power by your motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

First, double-check the Event Viewer for any errors around that time.  You never know when there could be an update that forces a reboot or a driver or something else that is causing your PC to crash.

Answer (score 0):

IF the problem is related to the CPU temperature and IF the computer turns off automatically (and i mean cutting off as opposed to initiating the regular shutdown procedure) as a protective measure, then you cannot influence this behaviour through the operating system. this is controlled at BIOS level.